# Regex match text in single quotes with specific second quote

Tags: regex

I have this php version

```
 $string = "'Fred's Company' is... ";
 // OR
 $string = "'Fred's Company' has... ";
 $match = "/'((?:[^']+|\b'\b)+)'/";
 preg_match_all($match, $string, $t);
```

So the regex above works if the string doesn't itself contain single quote so 'Fred Company', it will find `Fred Company`, however with the version above it will only find `Fred`.

To fix, I need the 2nd single quote to match the `' is` or `' has` version of the string, therefore getting back the full `Fred's Company is/has`,  and still work for `Fred Company is/has`.

How can I change the above regex for this ?

Comment: It's so much easier for readers to understand questions when they begin with a statement of the problem being addressed, followed by one or more illustrative examples, showing the desired result for each. If the author's code is not mentioned until after that is out of the way, readers will be happy. Here you are given a string containing some single-quoted text. Please say at the beginning what you want to do with that string.

Comment: How many single quotes can appear in the string? What do you want returned if there are 4 or more, if that could happen?

Comment: @CarySwoveland it is ok, I have accepted the answer, next time I'll open new question if I make same mistake :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a smart negative lookahead which asserts that the closing single quote does not occur inside two other outer single quotes:

```
$string = "'Fred's Company' has members in 'ATL'";
$match = "/'.*?'(?!\S)/";
preg_match_all($match, $string, $t);
print_r($t[0][0]);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'Fred's Company'
    [1] => 'ATL'
)
```

The regex pattern asserts that the single quote does not occur embedded within a word.  Admittedly, this fails for the edge case of possessive (genitive) `s`, e.g.

```
Fred's employees' paychecks are going up this year.
```

Comment: ah my bad! Already accepted, but I just realised this won't work if there's a 2nd quoted text in the string `'Fred's Company' has members in 'ATL'`, in which case it brings back the whole string - are u able to amend? Sorry :)

Comment: @CarySwoveland Actually, I would welcome you posting a better answer here.  In general, I don't see any obvious way which regex can cover all cases `:-)`

Comment: Tim, I don't understand the question, but I'll re-read it and try to think harder.

Comment: I think the OP just wants to capture all terms in single quotes, discounting quotes which might be grammatical in nature (e.g. apostrophes).

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, I already am aware of this (just read my answer).

Comment: Ah, yes. I didn't think I was saying anything that hadn't occurred to you. I was just commiserating about the loose ends...

Comment: I think any robust solution would need to "know" something about the context of single quotes.

Comment: yes my mistake, sorry i really appreciate this! Thats why initially I wanted to use the combo of 2nd single quote plus either `is` or `has`